# before_begin implementation of forward_list

Tags: c++11, forward-list

How is the `before_begin` method implemented in the context of a `std::forward_list`?

I have tried something like this:

```
template <class _Tp>
typename forward_list<_Tp>::iterator forward_list<_Tp>::before_begin() NOEXCEPT {
  return forward_list_iterator<_Tp>(new forward_list_node<_Tp>(_Tp(), m_pHead));
}

template <class _Tp>
typename forward_list<_Tp>::const_iterator forward_list<_Tp>::before_begin() const NOEXCEPT {
  return forward_list_const_iterator<_Tp>(new forward_list_node<_Tp>(_Tp(), m_pHead));
}
```

What I understood is that the `before_begin` method shall be used when calling `insert_after` `emplace_after` etc. Thus I made the method return an `iterator` to a new node that points to `m_pHead` and has a default value for the template type `_Tp`. However, I am unsure about two things:

1) As I am using templates, how can I get the default value? Is `_Tp()` a legal expression in order to get the default value for the specific type (with both primitive and user-defined types)?

2) As this method returns an `iterator` before `m_pHead`, if I call one of the `insert_after` overloaded methods with `before_begin` as the first argument, wouldn't I end up having the data inserted in the list, but without having the `m_pHead` updated?

My implementation of (one of the four overloads of) `insert_after` is as follows:

```
template <class _Tp>
void forward_list<_Tp>::insert_after(const_iterator _position, const _Tp& _value) {
  forward_list_node<_Tp>* _node = new forward_list_node<_Tp>(_value, _position.m_pNode->m_pNext);
  _position.m_pNode->m_pNext = _node;
}
```

Thank you very much for taking your time. :)

EDIT: According to the code in the link from T.C.'s answer, the `before_begin` should be implemented like this:

```
iterator before_begin() { return iterator(&head); }
```

However, this is how my `begin` is implemented:

```
template <class _Tp>
typename forward_list<_Tp>::iterator forward_list<_Tp>::begin() NOEXCEPT {
  return forward_list_iterator<_Tp>(m_pHead);
}
```

I don't really get how the `before_begin` implementation above should work (either that, or my `insert_after` is not written correctly).

EDIT 2: From what I understand so far, the `before_begin` should return the `m_pHead` and the `begin` should return `m_pHead->m_pNext`.. That doesn't really make much sense, as `begin` should implicitly refer to `m_pHead`, but it is a workaround I guess.

Comment: `before_begin` should definitely not be `new`'ing anything. [N2543](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2543.htm) has a straightforward sample implementation.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about their website. Thank you very much. However, I still have a question regarding this implementation, it seems to be returning the head? `iterator before_begin() { return iterator(&head); }`

Comment: Added an edit to the main post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea is this:

```
struct node_base {
    node_base * next;
};

template<class T>
struct node : node_base {
    T value;
};

template<class T>
struct forward_list_iter {
    forward_list_iter(node_base *pn) : pnode(pn) { }
    T& operator*() const { return static_cast<node<T>*>(pnode)->value; }
    forward_list_iter& operator++() { pnode = pnode->next; return *this; }
    // other stuff
    node_base* pnode;
};

template<class T>
struct forward_list {
    node_base head;
    forward_list_iter<T> before_begin() { 
        return forward_list_iter<T>(&head); 
    }
    forward_list_iter<T> begin() { 
        return forward_list_iter<T>(head.next); 
    }
    // other stuff
};
```

The `head` node is embedded in the `forward_list` itself, and is just a `node_base`, which just contains just a pointer to the next node. All other nodes are actually `node<T>`s, which derive from `node_base` and stores a value of type `T`. The iterator stores a `node_base *`, and casts it to a `node<T> *` when dereferenced. `before_begin()` points to `head`; `begin()` points to `head.next`, which is actually the first node to contain a value.